# document.head.appendChild(script); not working on android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

Hi all I'm using the following code to try and load jquery mobile. it works fine on an iphone but wont work on any Android phones, or blackberry. Does anyone know why

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js";
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

I've also tried 
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

Comment: Any particular Android browser?

Comment: Some BlackBerry browsers don't support JavaScript at all.